# Authentication does not save cookie

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a login form where I should save into cookie the authentication in case the user close and reopen the browser.

I tried with

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

With this code, I save the cookie into login

```
Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(Login1.UserName, True, 600)
Dim encTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
 Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket))
```

and here I read the cookie

```
Dim FormsAuthCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName) 
Dim usr As String = FormsAuthCookie.Value
Dim Ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(FormsAuthCookie.Value)
  usr = Ticket.Name & ""
```

The `FormsAuthookie.value` is always `NULL`, cannot understand what is wrong

Comment: Can you F12 to bring up tools and navigate to the application tab, expand the storage|cookies node and verify that your auth cookie is there and has a value?

Comment: I don't see you doing anything to create a persistent cookie (date expiration). Normal (volitile) cookies will go-away when you close a browser.

Comment: thanks guys, i added expiryng date on web.config and added code to add expiry, but this doesnt fix the problem